# Flash CS5 failing to open it's own documents

Tags: adobe-flash, adobe-cs5

Pretty disastrous really, on Friday I made a few tweaks to some production files, nothing out of the ordinary at all. Today, I cannot open a large number of my own documents.

Important:

1. I have only one version of CS on my WinXPSP3 machine, CS5
2. I created all of the unopenable documents in CS5
3. I have edited them above files successfully over the last few months
4. Nobody else even *tried* to open them, let alone actually managed to
5. Occassionally when I attempt to open a suspect file, it does actually open and is then fine (like 3 across 28 source files), but mostly I just get the 'Unexpected File Format' error followed by document auto-close.

Possibly important:

1. I recently uninstalled Flash Player, installed the Adobe 'official' archived Flash Player 7 version to do some version detection testing (oh dear, here we go)
2. I also subsequently finished the above testing, uninstalled FP7, reinstalled FP10 (non-debug)
3. Chrome fails to launch FP10 plugin occasionally, across a range of sites

Other than the Flash Player un/install business, nothing unusual as stated. It should also probably be noted that the un/installation of the player happened over a week ago, so may be totally unrelated.

Ugh, no source files, awesome Adobe.
d

Comment: Does creating a new file, saving it, and opening that work?

Comment: That does work, yep.

Comment: This doesn't help, but in future try setting up your test environment inside a virtual machine, instead of messing around with installing/uninstalling flash player on your development machine.

Comment: Ya, agreed, I'm almost embaressed to admit that I did the above :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, purely disastrous. So many people have had different versions of this "Unexpected file format." saving bug. Sometimes users can't save at all as Flash CS5 crashes during save. Sometimes your file is corrupt beyond repair. Sometimes you can harvest an XML file if you convert the corrupt .fla to .xlf format, and remove empty library item nodes... or something. It's just retarded and Adobe should be, and probably are, embaressed.

And interesting and horrific link detailing loads of people's woes: 
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/642378?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

1) Run Disk Utility, make sure sure your volume doesn't have problems that's messing up your files from being read -- I've had this happen to me before.

2) If it's an extension problem, go to System Preferences / Other / Default Apps, select the File Types tab.  This is an extension called RCDefaultApp by Carl Lindbern from Rubicode.  It will let you fix broken file associations.